# Размер таблицы с подписями легенд python plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, визуализация

подскажите пожалуйста , как подвинуть таблицу со списком легенд (она перекрывает подпись доли 'ROC')

sng_plot = athletes_sng.plot.pie(y = 'Athletes count',  labels = athletes_sng['NOC'], figsize = (8,8), rotatelabels = True, wedgeprops = {'linewidth': 3})

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ищите в коде что-то типа такого:

```
plt.legend("диаграмма", loc='upper right')
```

Меняйте:

```
loc = 'upper left'
```

[Справка тут.](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/legend_api.html)